# How to unescape in query_string double semicolons?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have following request:

```
/posts?from=45&q=mad;;depot&size=15
```

But controller params is:

```
{"from"=>"45",
 "q"=>"mad",
 "depot"=>nil,
 "size"=>"15"}
```

How it should looks like:

```
{"from"=>"45",
 "q"=>"mad;;depot",
 "size"=>"15"}
```

How to pass in Rails routes params with double semicolons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to encode your params first to

```
/posts?from=45&q=mad%3B%3Bdepot&size=15
```

Then Rails will recognize it correctly.

> For more information about encode URL: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: ok, it pass q param, but it isn't automatically decoded: `{"from"=>45,
 "q"=>"mad%3B%3Bdepot", "size"=>"15"}`, maybe is it some whitelist option in rails router to omit defined characters?

Comment: It's weird. Where and how do you get params value? When I tried above, my console so: `Parameters: {"from"=>"45", "q"=>"mad;;depot", "size"=>"15"}`