# Rails is not reading anything after ';'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, imageurl

I have a web api that parses a data url(data:image/png;base64,..) in a query parameter. However when I tried saving the data it becomes "data:image/png". Is there a way where I can tell rails to allow the whole data url string?

Comment: paste the parser we cannot guess what you did

Comment: Sorry, it's:
data = params[:data]
data then becomes: 'data:image/png', which means it is skipping everything after the semi colon.

Comment: do a `puts params.inspect` in your controller's action and show us the output.

Comment: @KMRakibulIslam the 'data' parameter is just: 'data:image/png', however I am passing: 
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAKsAAADVCAMAAAAfHvCaAAAAGFBMVEVYn%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2Bex%2B3U5vd7s%2Bfq8%2Fs0itq72PMLUPvtAAASvklEQVR4AbXBC0JqCQxEwT5Jd7L%2FHc8FdR4g%2BEGtEr8u%2FBHxu7otdzd%2FQPyqlmRp1Pw%2B8aukDfRa1fw28ZtWy4sa89vEb7LCi0zx28RvqgkvouW3id%2FU8pbtWmv5beJXRWNrRmp%2BnfhlHXZm%2BQPi95Vk%2FoD4fZbMHxC%2FryTzB8Tva435A%2BL3rcb8AfH7VjJ%2FQPy%2BHYk%2FIH5facwfEL8iaZcrnKyn%2BAPi57K2VL2WF1hJ%2FAHxQ2tJrg6HteXVjPkD4ge6V3J1%2....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unescape in query\_string double semicolons?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764518/how-to-unescape-in-query-string-double-semicolons)

Comment: Looks like you need to encode your params. Look at the above question that Jordan posted. Also see this: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ and test encoding your passed urm params.